# jQUery syntax for multiple groups of checkboxes, each with their own "check all" option

Tags: jquery, checkbox

My code generates HTML forms from a template, and populates them with whatever input elements are required by the data being processed at the time. The resulting forms contain groups of checkboxes, each of which have their own 'check all' box. E.g.:

```
<p>Your breakfast order</p>
<div class="a_bunch_of_checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll">Check All
<input type="checkbox">Toast
<input type="checkbox">Eggs
<input type="checkbox">Bacon
</div>

<p>Your lunch order</p>
<div class="a_bunch_of_checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll">Check All
<input type="checkbox">Salad
<input type="checkbox">Pizza
<input type="checkbox">Hot Dogs
</div>
```

Etc. (Obviously each "Check All" checkbox would check all boxes in that particular group only.)

I am not too well versed in javascript and jQuery, and I have tried but failed to come up with the appropriate jQuery code to register an event handler to the "check all" checkboxes.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Obviously jQuery is like PERL, in that "there's more than one way to do it". :-) Four answers, all with working examples, each of which helps me out in a different way. You guys rock!

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("change",'.checkAll',function(){
     $(this).closest('.a_bunch_of_checkboxes').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',$(this).is(':checked'));
  });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hdP7n/13/)**

Comment: nice solution, but it allows only one select and deselect. then it stops.

Comment: i get no errors, to specify the problem, it does not select the other checkboxes, deselect does work.

Comment: can you share me jsfiddle link with your problem statment so that i can look into it?

Comment: it is just yours, which is not working in ie11 win7. i think it is because of `attr` instead of `prop`.

Comment: can you try with my updated answer, I have replace `.attr()` with `.prop()`. Thanks @NinaScholz for pointing out this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try filtering **[`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** of `.checkAll`

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rVF6d/1/)

In case of dynamic elements :

```
$(document).on('click','.checkAll:checkbox',function(){
    $(this).siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

Reference:

- **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**
- **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**
- **[`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**
- **[`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**

Answer (score 2):

you jquery, check if that checkbox is checked then check all checkbox otherwise uncheck

```
 $('.checkAll').on('click',function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked','checked');
        }else{        
            $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked','');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/5fge4/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking the status of checkbox with class `checkAll`, and loop through each checkbox under the div and apply `checkAll` checkbox status to all other checkboxes:

```
$('.checkAll').click(function(event) {  //on click 
     var $boxes = $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="checkbox"]');  
     if(this.checked) { // check select status
         $boxes.each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
             this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes                
         });
     }else{
         $boxes.each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
             this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes under the checkAll checkbox                      
         });         
     }
 });
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/kWvkN/)**